Tailwind CSS grid-cols only working for grid-cols-4
I'm new to using tailwind CSS, and I'm running into a strange issue with using the grid-cols. For some reason, using the grid-cols-* for any size other then 4 doesn't work properly.
This works for and gives me the expected results
<div className="grid grid-cols-4  gap-4">
    <div>col1</div>
    <div>col2</div>
    <div>col3</div>
    <div>col4</div>
    <div>col5</div>
</div>


But if I change it to any other value
<div className="grid grid-cols-6  gap-4">
    <div>col1</div>
    <div>col2</div>
    <div>col3</div>
    <div>col4</div>
    <div>col5</div>
</div>


They basically lose the columns entirely. I'm not sure what's going on, and from others it seems like it's a config or setting thing? Other tailwindcss classes seem to work, and since grid-cols-4 is working, I'm assuming it's loading in the css properly. I'm also using nextui if that negatively impacts anything.
Here's my tailwind.config.js if it's useful -
import {nextui} from '@nextui-org/react'

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './layouts/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  darkMode: "class",
  plugins: [nextui()],
}


Ensure your tailwind.config.js file includes all necessary utilities. If you're using a custom content path, make sure it correctly points to all your JSX/HTML files.
Here's my example configuration
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}


I just added my snippet of the tailwind.config.js into my comment - my code is located within the components directory. Since grid-cols-4 works, doesn't that mean that tailwindcss was loaded in? I think I read somewhere that perhaps there's something else overwriting the specific classname, but I don't have anything else other then nextui installed
